# Entrada de dados em python com diversas linhas

Tags: python-3.x, lista, algoritmo, ciência-da-computação, entrada-de-dados

Gostaria de entender como dar entrada em diversos dados (int, float, str...) por linha porém de maneira repetida (ou seja, em várias linhas) de modo que eu consiga salvar cada entrada dada.

Entendo que terei que usar uma lista para armazenar cada entrada e, usando split, consigo dar entrada em diversos dados na mesma linha, mas me perco na hora de fazer isso com várias linhas.

Por exemplo:

```
linha = input().split()

lista = []
for item in range(5):
    x = int(linha[item])
    lista.append(x)
print(lista)
```

Esse código me proporciona uma linha com diversos dados (inteiros) de entrada, gostaria de repetir esse processo em quantas linhas eu desejar e com os diversos tipos de dados que eu quiser. Porém, por ser iniciante, ainda não me acostumei com a sintaxe.

Comment: "quantas linhas eu desejar" é fácil e pode ser explicado... Agora "com os diversos tipos de dados que eu quiser" precisa ser esclarecido... Como você decidiria que tipo de dado deve ser o input do usuário?

Comment: "Como você decidiria que tipo de dado deve ser o input do usuário? " Vamos supor que o problema peça algo como "um int seguido de um string", por exemplo.

"fácil e pode ser explicado." ficaria muito grato pela explicação.

Comment: Estou tentando entender o seu problema pra formular uma resposta adequada :D ... Então vai ser pré determinado quantos inputs o usuário vai inserir e quais os tipos de cada input?

Comment: Isso, exatamente. Vou tentar quebrar meu problema] em etapas. 1 - Vamos supor que eu pré determine o range primeiro. Por exemplo. Serão x linhas com y caracteres em cada linha.  2 - Esses caracteres podem ser int, float, strings...  3 - Preciso armazenar os dados de cada linha em uma lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) sempre retorna uma string, para trabalharmos com outros tipos de dados precisamos manipular esta string, então vamos por partes.

---

## Receber múltiplos valores

Podemos resolver este problema com diferentes abordagens, exemplo:

#### Recebendo todos os valores de uma única vez.

Podemos receber uma string com todos os valores separados por espaço em branco e utilizar o método [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para "quebrar" esta string em uma lista de strings. Exemplo:

```
linha = input("Digite os valores separados por espaço")
# ex.: '1 2 3 4 5'
valores = linha.split()
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Se você quer converter todos os valores para inteiro você pode utilizar:

- Um `for` para iterar nos valores, converter o valor e depois adicionar à lista de resultado com [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

  ```
  linha = input("Digite os valores separados por espaço")
  valores = []

  for valor in linha.split():
      valores.append(int(valor))
  ```
- A função [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para aplicar uma função em todos os itens de um iterável e criar uma nova lista com o resultado da função para cada posição da lista.

  ```
  linha = input("Digite os valores separados por espaço")
  valores = linha.split()
  valores_convertidos = map(int, valores)
  ```
- Uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para iterar e converter todos os valores:

  ```
  linha = input("Digite os valores separados por espaço")
  valores = linha.split()
  valores_convertidos = [int(valor) for valor in valores]
  ```

#### Recebendo um valor de cada vez

Você pode receber um numero indefinido de inputs utilizando um loop e definindo um critério de parada.

Por exemplo, receber números inteiros enquanto o usuário inserir valores válidos:

```
valores = []

while True:
    try:
        linha = int(input("Digite um número:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Valor inválido, saindo do loop")
        break

    valores.append(linha)
```

No código acima estou criando um loop "infinito" que se repetirá enquanto a conversão do input do usuário para `int` não falhar. Quando ela falhar lançará um `ValueError` executando o [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) dentro do `except`

---

## Recebendo um número específico de variáveis com tipos pré definidos

Você pode receber um número específico de inputs usando a função [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) como você mesmo postou na sua pergunta:

```
valores = []

for _ in range(5):
    valor = input("Digite algo: ")
    valores.append(valor)
```

O próximo passo é definir os tipos de dados que devemos receber. Poderíamos usar números inteiros ou até mesmo strings para definir os tipos de dados.

Exemplo:

```
# 0: int
# 1: str
# 2: float
tipos = [0, 1, 1, 0, 2]
valores = []

for tipo in tipos:
    valor = input("Digite algo: ")

    if tipo == 0:
        valores.append(int(valor))
    elif tipo == 1:
        valores.append(valor)  # já é string
    elif tipo ==2:
        valores.append(float(valor))
    else:
        print("Tipo inválido, nenhum valor adicionado")
```

Não vou aprofundar muito nas melhorias que poderiam ser feitas no código acima pois é apenas um demonstrativo de como poderia ser feito.

Ao invés de ter vários `if` para cada tipo que você gostaria de ter, você poderia usar uma lista de funções que recebem uma string e retornem o tipo que você deseja. No python, funções são ["cidadãos de primeira classe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), isso significa que você pode passá-las como parâmetros para outras funções, atribuí-las a variáveis, etc...

Então é possível fazer algo como:

```
meu_int = int
valor = meu_int("10")
print(valor)  # 10
```

Aplicando este conceito, refazendo o exemplo e removendo os `if` ficaria:

```
tipos = [int, str, str, int, float]
valores = []

for tipo in tipos:
    valor = input("Digite algo: ")
    valores.append(tipo(valor))
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOpt-412801-6333)</sup>

Dessa maneira você está especificando que você quer que o usuário insira 5 valores, sendo eles um inteiro, 2 strings, 1 inteiro e 1 float, respectivamente. Sem contar que você pode criar suas próprias funções ou classes que recebem uma string como entrada e retornem um objeto do tipo que você quiser.

## Conclusão

Como o assunto é genérico, acabou que a resposta ficou um pouco ampla, mas o importante é que você entenda que existem várias abordagens para o mesmo problema e espero ter dado material o suficiente para você ter um ponto de partida para novos estudos e novas dúvidas.

Comment: Fernando, de fato, sua resposta satisfez em absoluto tudo aquilo que eu precisava. Honestamente, não sei como agradecer, por que realmente ajudou muito. Muito obrigado!

Comment: A intenção é ajudar mesmo, fico feliz que tenha dado certo.
Se minha resposta satisfez em absoluto tudo aquilo que você precisava, considere marcá-la como aceita. Não digo isso por causa de ponto de reputação, é mais porque alguém vai cair nessa página com as mesmas dúvidas no futuro e se é assim mesmo que você pensa faria mais sentido para o futuro visitante entender que essa resposta foi mais útil para a sua dúvida.

Comment: Como sou novo aqui, ainda não havia percebido esses detalhes. Marcada como aceita. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

> Abuse e use do `try`

```
texto = '''1
teste
1.5
balb
512

1,4'''
# Separa String por linhas e cria uma lista
lst = texto.split('\n')

lst_tratada = []
# Para cada valor que estiver na lista
for i in lst:
    # Tenta registrar o valor como int e vai para o próximo laço, senão continua
    try:
        lst_tratada.append(int(i))
        continue
    except:
        pass
    # Tenta registrar o valor como float e vai para o próximo laço, senão continua
    try:
        lst_tratada.append(float(i))
        continue
    except:
        # Se não conseguir nenhum dos dois, tratar como string
        lst_tratada.append(i)

print(lst_tratada)
```

> Um approach mais simples, a partir de um método:

```
def var_parser(x):
    try: # Tenta retornar x como inteiro
        return int(x)
    except: # Se não obtiver exito, continuar
        pass
    try: # Tenta retornar x como float
        return float(x)
    except: # Se não obtive exito, retornar x 
        return x


texto = '''1
teste
1.5
balb
512

1,4'''

lst = texto.split('\n')

lst_tratada = []
for i in lst:
    lst_tratada.append(var_parser(i))

print(lst_tratada)
```

Comment: não chegou a ser exatamente o que eu preciso. Ou, infelizmente, eu não compreendi sua resposta. No caso, eu mesmo irei fornecer os dados e eles serão vários por linha e serão várias linhas (com vários dados). Mas eu achei interessante o uso do split('\n'). Estou tentando ver como usá-lo. Obrigado!

Comment: É bem simples. Primeiro ele tenta registrar na lista como int, se não conseguir ele tenta como float, e se não conseguir novamente, registra como string. Agora essa do split('\n'), tipo... O pulo da linha é registrado como \n, por isso utilizamos split('\n') para separar por linha.
O print() mesmo do python sempre coloca no final da linha '\n', por isso no terminal sempre irá para a próxima linha após usar a função print()

Comment: Ahhhh, ficou claro agora. Vou tentar implementar no meu caso e ver se funciona, agradeço!

Comment: Recomendo você dar uma lida no Try e Except. Eles são ótimos tanto para tratamento de erro, assim como para testes lógicos, no qual foi utilizado nesse exemplo.